# Cosine similarity

Tags: c++, performance

Is there anything to make the cosine similarity function more optimized in terms of CPU execution time?

```
double cosine_similarity(double *A, double *B, unsigned int size)
{
    double mul = 0.0, d_a = 0.0, d_b = 0.0 ;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i) 
    {
        mul += A[i] * B[i] ;
        d_a += A[i] * A[i] ;
        d_b += B[i] * B[i] ;
    }
    return mul / (sqrt(d_a) * sqrt(d_b)) ;
}
```

Comment: Depending on the size of A and B, passing by (const) reference could be faster, since there is less memory to be copied onto the stack.

Comment: Also you could reverse the loop, as 'for(int i = size; i--){...}', so you dont have to compare i to size in every step.

Comment: @M.Hoffmann Comments are for seeking clarification to the question. Please write all suggestions as answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Check for Possible Errors**

There are a number of possible errors in the code:

1. The variable `size` may be zero which will lead to division by zero.
2. The vectors A and B may not be the same length, if the `size` variable
   is the size of the shorter vector this is not a problem, but if the
   `size` variable is the size of the larger vector this can lead to unknown
   behavior.
3. Either d_a or d_b can add up to zero, which can lead to division by zero
   as @coderodde pointed out.

C++ provides the exception class [std:exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception) that has multiple sub classes.
Two of the classes are `std::runtime_error` and `std::logic_error`. Item 1 and 2
above belong in the `std::logic_error` class, item 3 belongs in the
`std::runtime_error` class.

**Code Readability and Maintainability**

The code has:

```
double mul = 0.0, d_a = 0.0, d_b = 0.0 ;
```

This is less readable and maintainable than putting the initialization on separate lines:

```
double mul = 0.0;
double d_a = 0.0;
double d_b = 0.0;
```

**Direct Addressing Versus Indirect Addressing**

The the most efficient way to write the function is to use [direct addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode) rather than indirect addressing. Since the code is already passing pointers
use the pointers rather than indexing them.

```
double cosine_similarity(double *A, double *B, unsigned int size)
{
    double mul = 0.0;
    double d_a = 0.0;
    double d_b = 0.0 ;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        mul += *A * *B;
        d_a += *A * *A;
        d_b += *B * *B;
        A++;
        B++;
    }

    if (d_a == 0.0f || d_b == 0.0f)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(
                "cosine similarity is not defined whenever one or both "
                "input vectors are zero-vectors.");
    }

    return mul / (sqrt(d_a) * sqrt(d_b)) ;
}
```

**Using Container Classes Can be Safer as Well as Efficient**

The container classes such as [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) provide safer containers than C style arrays. If the number of elements in the array are know, the std::array class is more efficient. If the number of elements in the array are not known `std::vector` provides a flexible as well as convenient way to store values.

These container classes provide additional information such as the size
of the array/vector and iterators for direct addressing. They also allow
for indexing through the 'array'.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

double cosine_similarity_vectors(std::vector<double> A, std::vector<double>B)
{
    double mul = 0.0;
    double d_a = 0.0;
    double d_b = 0.0 ;

    if (A.size() != B.size())
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Vector A and Vector B are not the same size");
    }

    // Prevent Division by zero
    if (A.size() < 1)
    {
        throw std::logic_error("Vector A and Vector B are empty");
    }

    std::vector<double>::iterator B_iter = B.begin();
    std::vector<double>::iterator A_iter = A.begin();
    for( ; A_iter != A.end(); A_iter++ , B_iter++ )
    {
        mul += *A_iter * *B_iter;
        d_a += *A_iter * *A_iter;
        d_b += *B_iter * *B_iter;
    }

    if (d_a == 0.0f || d_b == 0.0f)
    {
        throw std::logic_error(
                "cosine similarity is not defined whenever one or both "
                "input vectors are zero-vectors.");
    }

    return mul / (sqrt(d_a) * sqrt(d_b));
}
```

Comment: As far as i know you can put B_iter and A_iter into the for loop as they are the same type. `for( std::vector<double>::iterator A_iter = A.begin(), B_iter = B.begin(); A_iter != A.end(); A_iter++ , B_iter++ )`

Answer (score 7):

Since $$\sqrt{D_a} \sqrt{D_b} = \sqrt{D_a D_b}$$
you can get rid of one call to **`sqrt`**

```
double cosine_similarity2(double *A, double *B, unsigned int size)
{
    double mul = 0.0, d_a = 0.0, d_b = 0.0 ;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        mul += A[i] * B[i] ;
        d_a += A[i] * A[i] ;
        d_b += B[i] * B[i] ;
    }

    if (d_a == 0 || d_b == 0)
    {
        throw runtime_error(
                "cosine similarity is not defined whenever one or both "
                "input vectors are zero-vectors.");
    }

    return mul / (sqrt(d_a * d_b)) ;
}
```

**Minor**

Usually people don't put a single space before the semicolon **`;`**. However, usually a single space is put straight after **`for`**:

```
for (int i = 0; ..., ++i) 
{  ^
    ...
}
```

**Divide by zero**

Note that **`sqrt(d_a * d_b) == 0`** only when at least one of the input vectors is a zero vector. However, cosine similarity *assumes* that the two input vectors are not zero-vectors, so it makes sense to me to throw an exception when it happens.

**Divide by zero ++**

As 200_success advised, you can omit the entire exception-throwing code and just proceed to division by zero: that will return a special **NaN** value ("Not a Number").

Comment: How can I get rid of divide by zero as (d_a * d_b) can be zero if all the elements of the two array is all zero?

Comment: 1) I'm not convinced that an exception would be better than a NaN result. 2) sqrt(_a_ * _b_) is not the same as sqrt(_a_) * sqrt(_b_) if _a_ or _b_ is negative.

Comment: @200_success Take another look at \$a\$ or \$b\$. They **can't** be negative. However, thank you for your suggestion; I will add it to my answer.

Comment: @200_success I am aware of existence of NaN, yet I would personally choose to avoid it since it "infects" everything it comes to operate with, yielding (silently) a NaN result.

Comment: You might also want to benchmark the results of splitting the [single loop into three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8547778/why-is-one-loop-so-much-slower-than-two-loops), if this function will be used on large vectors or very frequently.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating cosine similarity between \$n\$ things only require calculating your square root (\$d\$) for \$n\$ times instead of \$n \space x \space n\$ times.

If you write a function that calculate cosine similarity between n things instead of just two things, you can save some time on calculating the square root.

Alternatively, write a function that calculate cosine similarity between two things with an array of the square roots as an argument.